# python accessing variable of high level from lower level class

Tags: python

I have a class inside a class like this:

```
class Robot(object):
      def __init__(self):
         self.name = 'ganken'
      class Speaker(object):
          pass
```

Let’s say I want to access `Robot.name` from Speaker, how do I do that

Comment: Why are you nesting classes? It offers no advantage in Python.

Comment: There is no `Robot.name`. You only define name on an instance. For this question to mean anything, you have to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: And don't forget to indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Speaker` a sub class of `Robot`:

```
class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'ganken'

class Speaker(Robot):
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
```

When you make an instance of `Speaker`, it will now have the name ganken associated with it.

```
s = Speaker
s.get_name()
```

Output:

```
'ganken'
```

You could have also called `s.name` and it would have still returned `'ganken'`, but usually you want to define functions in your class to get and set different attributes of your class (look up getters and setters if you want more information).

---

I might have misunderstood your question. If you want to access the name of a instance of a Robot class in your Speaker class (and don't necessarily want to make Speaker a subclass of Robot), you could define your class as:

```
class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'ganken'

class Speaker(object):
    def get_robot_name(self, robot):
        return robot.name
```

Notice that you can pass a robot instance into the `get_robot_name` function in this example.

Demo:

```
r = Robot()
s = Speaker()
s.get_robot_name(r)

'ganken'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I’m studying python through my senior code and there are a bunch classes inside class which make me confused a little bit, but I got my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following where you create a speaker object in the Robot class if you are looking for a nested class solution. But i don't know what is the reason for you to do this though.

Try this assuming **Python3** environment:

```
class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'ganken'
        self.speaker = self.createSpeaker()

    def createSpeaker(self):
        return Robot.Speaker(self)

    class Speaker:
        def __init__(self,robot):
            self.robot = robot
        def say_name(self):
            return f'Name: {self.robot.name}'

robot = Robot()
print(robot.speaker.say_name())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
print(Robot().name)
```

Just call it then access it

Output is:

```
ganken
```